# JPlayer - Play tracks in sync

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jplayer

I have set up jPlayer with multiple tracks which I want to auto play all in sync, I have added the tracks and they all auto play fine, how can I make them auto play together when they have all loaded? I think I can do this through events, but I'm not sure how to do this.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ui-slider-handle').draggable();        
  
  // Base Track   
     $("#base-track").jPlayer({
         ready: function(event) {
             $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                 title: "Base Track",
                 mp3: "audio/track1/audio_test_layer_base.mp3"
      }).jPlayer("play");
    },
     ended: function() {
       $(this).jPlayer("play");
     },
         swfPath: "/js",
         supplied: "mp3",
   preload: "auto",
      volume: 0.8,
      muted: false,    
     }); 
     
          
     
     // Track 1   
     $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
         ready: function(event) {
             $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                 title: "Layer 1",
                 mp3: "audio/track1/audio_test_layer1.mp3"
      }).jPlayer("play");
    },
     ended: function() {
       $(this).jPlayer("play");
     },
         swfPath: "/js",
         supplied: "mp3, oga",
   preload: "auto",
      volume: 0.0,
      muted: false,    
     }); 
     
        $('#slider').slider({ 
        min: 0, 
  max: 1,
  range: "min",        
  step: 0.01, 
        value: 0,
        orientation: "horizontal",
             slide: function(event, ui) {
           var volume = ui.value / 1;
           $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("volume", volume);
                    $('#scene1').css('opacity', ui.value)
       }             
        })
 
     // Track 2   
     $("#jquery_jplayer_2").jPlayer({
         ready: function(event) {
             $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                 title: "Layer 2",
                 mp3: "audio/track1/audio_test_layer2.mp3"
      }).jPlayer("play");
    },
     ended: function() {
       $(this).jPlayer("play");
     },
         swfPath: "/js",
         supplied: "mp3",
   preload: "auto",
      volume: 0.3,
      muted: false,    
     }); 
     
     $('#slider2').slider({ 
        min: 0, 
        max: 1, 
        step: 0.01, 
        value: 0.3,
        orientation: "horizontal",
             slide: function(event, ui) {
           var volume = ui.value / 1;
           $("#jquery_jplayer_2").jPlayer("volume", volume);
                    $('#scene2').css('opacity', ui.value)
       }                 
        }) 

     // Track 3   
     $("#jquery_jplayer_3").jPlayer({
         ready: function(event) {
             $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                 title: "Layer 3",
                 mp3: "audio/track1/audio_test_layer3.mp3"
      }).jPlayer("play");
    },
     ended: function() {
       $(this).jPlayer("play");
     },
         swfPath: "/js",
         supplied: "mp3",
   preload: "auto",
      volume: 0.0,
      muted: false,    
     }); 
     
     $('#slider3').slider({ 
        min: 0, 
        max: 1, 
        step: 0.01, 
        value: 0,
        orientation: "horizontal",
             slide: function(event, ui) {
           var volume = ui.value / 1;
           $("#jquery_jplayer_3").jPlayer("volume", volume);
                    $('#scene3').css('opacity', ui.value)
       }                 
        }) 
    
     // Track 4   
     $("#jquery_jplayer_4").jPlayer({
         ready: function(event) {
             $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                 title: "Layer 4",
                 mp3: "audio/track1/audio_test_layer4.mp3"
      }).jPlayer("play");
    },
     ended: function() {
       $(this).jPlayer("play");
     },
         swfPath: "/js",
         supplied: "mp3",
   preload: "auto",
      volume: 0,
      muted: false,    
     }); 
     
     $('#slider4').slider({ 
        min: 0, 
        max: 1, 
        step: 0.01, 
        value: 0,
        orientation: "horizontal",
             slide: function(event, ui) {
           var volume = ui.value / 1;
           $("#jquery_jplayer_4").jPlayer("volume", volume);
                    $('#scene4').css('opacity', ui.value)
       }                 
        }) 


     // Track 5   
     $("#jquery_jplayer_5").jPlayer({
         ready: function(event) {
             $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                 title: "Layer 5",
                 mp3: "audio/track1/audio_test_layer5.mp3"
      }).jPlayer("play");
    },
     ended: function() {
       $(this).jPlayer("play");
     },
         swfPath: "/js",
         supplied: "mp3",
   preload: "auto",
      volume: 0.8,
      muted: false,    
     }); 
     
     $('#slider5').slider({ 
        min: 0, 
        max: 1, 
        step: 0.01, 
        value: 0.8,
        orientation: "horizontal",
             slide: function(event, ui) {
           var volume = ui.value / 1;
           $("#jquery_jplayer_5").jPlayer("volume", volume);
                    $('#scene5').css('opacity', ui.value)
       }                 
        }) 

     // Track 6   
     $("#jquery_jplayer_6").jPlayer({
         ready: function(event) {
             $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                 title: "Layer 6",
                 mp3: "audio/track1/audio_test_layer6.mp3"
      }).jPlayer("play");
    },
     ended: function() {
       $(this).jPlayer("play");
     },
         swfPath: "/js",
         supplied: "mp3",
   preload: "auto",
      volume: 0.0,
      muted: false,    
     }); 
     
     $('#slider6').slider({ 
        min: 0, 
        max: 1, 
        step: 0.01, 
        value: 0,
        orientation: "horizontal",
             slide: function(event, ui) {
           var volume = ui.value / 1;
           $("#jquery_jplayer_6").jPlayer("volume", volume);
                    $('#scene6').css('opacity', ui.value)
       }                 
        })         
        
        
    });</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add preload: 'auto' to jplayer
as 
jPlayer supports the HTML5 preload argument, such that adding preload: 'auto' would make the track when loaded to start playing so all the tracks would play in the same time.

Example for Track 3 :

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_3").jPlayer({
        ready: function(event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                title: "Layer 3",
                mp3: "audio/track1/audio_test_layer3.mp3"
        }).jPlayer("play");
    },
        ended: function() {
            $(this).jPlayer("play");
        },
        preload: 'auto',//here add it to all tracks
        swfPath: "/js",
        supplied: "mp3",
        preload: "auto",
        volume: 0.0,
        muted: false,    
    });
```

I hope it helped you

Have a nice day